# How to Use ExecutorService.submit(Runnable r, T result) method?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to find a way to utilize ExecutorService.submit(Runnable r, T result) method , but cannot find/Imagine any.
 Can anyone explain how this method is best utilised with a code example.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929342/choose-between-executorservices-submit-and-executorservices-execute).

Comment: Yes, tried  ExecutorService.submit(Runnable r) and  ExecutorService.submit(Callable c) , both which i have understood , but not  ExecutorService.submit(Runnable r, T result)  method , any pointer will be helpful

Comment: @EmanueleGiona , i have already went over the question thanks , but i cannot imagine any ways to utilise ExecutorService.submit(Runnable r, T result) method.

Comment: Glue code for when you have a `Runnable` and need a `Future`, and you can't change those.

Answer (score 1):

You are perhaps wondering what the point of this method is? If so, you're not the only one :)

- [These people are wondering the same thing ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456504/what-does-result-in-executorservice-submitrunnable-task-t-result-do#6456595)
- [... And so are these people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306978/futuretask-with-runnable-and-results)

And if you are wondering *am **I** missing something here?* ... you're probably not. I've never encountered a use case for that method or, at least, a use case which was compelling and could not be achieved in any other way.

Comment: You're assuming that other ways are available for use. If you're working with a constrained environment trying to glue two pieces of code together, it might be useful to essentially convert a `Runnable` to a `Callable`.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not claiming that there is no possible need for it **ever**. I'm just saying that I have never found a use for it and there are pre existing questions on SO which strongly suggest that this experience is not unique to me :)

Comment: @glitch Thanks for lending a hand